# How do I get 2 meshes to join without joining the texture, along with another question

Tags: mesh, texturing, modifiers

So I'm making the tree, I used the skin modifier to make the base of the tree. When I join the leaf mesh and tree mesh together they lose the skin modifier and the leaf mesh goes all crazy like only some parts of it were inverted. The leaf mesh is made out of Icospheres.

The tree mesh also goes back to its bone. I'm new to Blender so I don't know the terms for things, but the tree goes back to where it looks like a disfigured stickman. So how do I join the meshes without them changing texture and without the tree turning into a stickman who got in a car wreck?

[image]

Comment: I suggest you see a tutorial on child parent  relationship which can be an option for you.  You can also search here at BSE.  Objects can be visually and functionally connected this way without the [join] operation.  Also investigate how modifiers can be applied.  The order of object selection for a [join] can affect the outcome.

Comment: Please show your work as a Blender screen capture.